# Do Lisp apps and webapps need special input sanitizing?

Tags: security, clojure, lisp

**EDIT 3** Quite some new development have happened since I asked this question.  Basically I wasn't "seeing things" and webapps written in Clojure have been found to be vulnerable, which prompted changes in Clojure 1.5 and *very* heated discussion on the Clojure Google groups.

Here's a quote from someone on Hacker News about the changes in Clojure 1.5:

> Another slightly interesting thing is the sudden enhancement to
>   read-eval and EDN[2]. That's mainly because of the rough weather
>   Ruby/Rubygems was in with the YAML-exploits, which caused a heated
>   discussion on how the Clojure reader should act by default.

Holes have been found and it's too late to really fix Clojure, so *read-eval* shall still ship by default set to *true* (because otherwise it would break too many things). And anyone parsing inputs in Clojure should not use the default read functions but the EDN ones.

So I certainly wasn't seeing things and it didn't take long (not even 18 months) for people to find ways to attack common Clojure webapp stacks.

**EDIT 2** I didn't know it but my question is a dupe of the following question (which has been described as a 'killer question'): [Lisp data security/validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000193)

If anyone's interested in the answer(s) to this question, I'd suggest they open the above question and read the answers made there by Lisp gurus instead of the ones of the type *"nothing to see here, move along, it's just like PHP or JavaScript"*.

**EDIT**: I'd like to know if, somehow, because it is Lisp, it would be "easier" for an attacker to transform "data" (i.e. "crafted user input with a malicious intent") into "code".  For example, do I need to escape/replace all the parentheses in the user input before starting to "evaluate" / parse or whatever the data?

**Original question**

I'm still reading about Lisp and suddenly I was wondering, with this entire "code is data" / "data is code" thing, do Lisp need to perform input sanitizing in order to prevent attacks?

I was thinking specifically of webapps, say when a user does some HTTP POST.

What if the data he's sending contains things like:

```
This is some malicious (eval '(nasty-stuff (...)) or whatever.
```

*(I'm no Lisp programmer, it's just an example of what I've got in mind, it's not meant to be actually mean code)*

Is there anything special to keep in mind due to how Lisp works?  For example if some dark-side hacker would know that some webserver is running on Clojure, can he exploit that fact and then inject "code between parentheses" that would then be evaluated on the webserver?

Is this a concern at all when receiving/parsing user data (and hence potentially crafted data) from Lisp?

Comment: "Easier" is relatively meaningless when talking about exploits. As ObscureRobot correctly noted suspect everything or better still just don't `eval` user input. LISP is really not particularly special as Robot also noted.

Comment: There is hardly any reason to use eval in production code, unless you are providing an online evaluator.

Comment: @ObscureRobot: dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000193

Comment: I don't see how it's any different than any other language that has an EVAL.  You say to go read the "Lisp gurus" at the other question but they say exactly the same thing, i.e., never use EVAL.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written some webapps in Lisp (i.e. Common Lisp) and here are the things I've kept in mind:

- if you use `read`, you should always set `*read-eval*` to `nil` for any untrusted data
- if you are dealing with code generation - for example, HTML, JS, CSS or SQL generation - which is very common in Lisp-land, you shouldn't forget to use the sanitizing facilities provided by the corresponding libraries (not use raw input strings)

Basically, that's all. Moreover, since it's Lisp, it usually makes your system less prone to attack, because:

- there are no standard attacks (as Lisp's use is relatively rare)
- the system is rather secure in terms of defaults - this isn't unique, but many web-oriented languages (like PHP in the first place) suffer from insecurity by default, although it is mitigated by modern frameworks

Comment: I'm accepting this and suggesting people who're after more great answer to see the ones in the dupe here (my question here is the dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000193    It's exactly the same question...

Answer (score 3):

You should always assume that injection attacks are possible until proven otherwise. Without knowing more about your specific Lisp environment and what you are comparing it with, it is impossible to answer whether you need "special" sanitization.

- We know that machine code attacks are possible.
- We know that SQL injection is possible.
- We should assume that it is possible to hijack any turing-complete system, whether it is hardware or software.

Note that the soft barrier between "code" and "data" is not unique to Lisp. `perl`, once the workhorse of the web world has [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html). So [does PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). It looks like Java bytecode injection may be possible as well.

Comment: @Cedric Martin, you probably need to work a little more on the question instead of downvoting valid answers to what the question seems to be. Your new edit explains a lot more of what you meant.

Comment: I *am* familiar with Lisp, but that doesn't matter. Yes, Lisp is extremely permissive when it comes to treating data as code, but it is hardly unique. Sanitize your data!

Comment: @Cedric Martin, it all comes down to what you _do_ with the data. If you escape it and insert it in a database, then it will obviously not be executed. If you display it verbatim, then it depends on how the engine that displays it works. If it doesn't do any escaping of its own, then it probably will get executed. Take a look at how the engine works.

Comment: Perhaps I was being too pedantic when I said "special" sanitization above. Of course you want to escape user input to ensure that it isn't interpreted. You may want to do things like look for unbalanced parentheses and forbid such input. But I consider such tasks to be isomorphic to the sort of sanitization that you'd do on input if you were writing perl/Mason or PHP. Or anything, really.

Comment: @Radu, as a Lisp user, this answer addresses the question perfectly - regardless of language, unsanitized input can and will wreak havok. Lisp's Code as data paradigm changes nothing - you shouldn't be `eval`-ing user input.

Comment: @tobyodavies, exactly my point. Always escape. If you do need to use `eval`, then escape the user input for lisp. Same as in PHP for example. If you need to use something like `$a = eval('$b - ' . $userData)`, escape `$userData` for PHP. Eval is evil though, so if you don't absolutely need to use it, then better not use it.

Comment: The fact that "eval" is so close to "evil" is a hint.

Answer (score 2):

It really does boil down to: don't use READ and don't use EVAL. You need to know exactly what you are sending to either or both of those functions, as well as the contexts within which they are executed. If you do not call either of these, then you're fine.

Comment: Wait, so in contrast to Scheme, LISP does evaluation in `read`?

Comment: @leppie: yes, the reader macro #.(form) is for evaluation at read time. Quite handy in certain circumstances. Quite deadly in most others.

Comment: @johanbev: Reason #61 why I prefer Scheme over LISP/CL. ;P